# How do I load and use native library in java?

Tags: java, native

I've got a java class, calling a native method and trying to load library:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Main {

    public static native String getMyString(String s);

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // System.out.println("here!");

        String s2 = getMyString("string text");
        for (Byte b : s2.getBytes("UTF-8")) {
            System.out.print(b);
            System.out.print(",");
        }

    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("mylib.so");
    }

}
```

The "mylib.so" is in the directory, where Main.class is located.

When I run `java Main` I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mylib.so in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1856)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:24)
```

What should I change for this to wark?

I've tried setting library full path without success

Comment: Unless you've coded for JNI, you're probably not going to get much further even *after* you successfully load your .so.  Please check out the Sun JNI tutorial: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html

Answer (score 10):

Do the following:

- Use System.loadLibrary("mylib");
- Copy mylib.so to libmylib.so
- Run java -Djava.library.path=/root/ Main

Comment: Also use -Djava.library.path=path-to-lib-file when starting java.

Comment: I made the changes and run the program with java Main -Djava.library.path=/root/, without any success

Comment: Note that the path passed to `-Djava.library.path` must be an **absolute** path.

Answer (score 6):

### "How to load native library"

```
public final class NativeLibsLoaderUtil {
    private static final String JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH = "java.library.path";
    private static final String SYS_PATHS = "sys_paths";

    private NativeLibsLoaderUtil() {
    }

    private static void addLibsToJavaLibraryPath(final String tmpDirName) {
        try {
            System.setProperty(JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH, tmpDirName);
            /* Optionally add these two lines */
            System.setProperty("jna.library.path", tmpDirName);
            System.setProperty("jni.library.path", tmpDirName);
            final Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField(SYS_PATHS);
            fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
            fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }   
}
```

Where tmpDirName is a directory where you store your library.
Or you can modify above class and use temp directory from your system property, like this:

```
/**
 * Temporary directory system property name
 */
private static final String JAVA_IO_TMPDIR = "java.io.tmpdir";

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
private static File getTempDir() {
    final String tmpDirName = System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR);
    final File tmpDir = new File(tmpDirName);
    if (!tmpDir.exists()) {
        tmpDir.mkdir();
    }
    return tmpDir;
}
```

!But first you have to copy there your native lib :)

Then to load native library call "addLibsToJavaLibraryPath" method in static block in "most root" class before any class constructor was executed.

```
static {
    NativeLibsLoaderUtil.addLibsToJavaLibraryPath("/tmp");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the so to library path:
[-Djava.libarary.path=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195778/java-error-cannot-find-library-in-java-library-path)  (this is in the java command).

if you run from eclipse:
[How to add native library to "java.library.path" with Eclipse launch (instead of overriding it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled opencv, on installation you should have seen something like:

```
make install:
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/java/opencv4/libopencv_java460.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/java/opencv4/opencv-460.jar
```

make a hard link to the /usr/lib/ folder:

```
$ sudo ln /usr/local/share/java/opencv4/libopencv_java460.so /usr/lib/libopencv_java460.so
```

And then just run:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

that he will get the *.so

Answer (score -7):

As Reimeus answered. 
Or you can use 
System.load("/Library/Path/libsample.so");

Comment: ... which makes your answer redundant.