# Can't run Scala project involving JavaFX and native library "LeapC"

Tags: java, scala, javafx

I'm generally a C/ C++ programmer but I got this task in Scala (that builds on Java if I'm not mistaken) and decided to try it out. First, I have to get the program to run, as I want to see what its like. This is what I'm trying to accomplish here. I have not written any code in the project myself, as this is software is a few years old, but I got the task to add some features to it.

As the title suggests, I can compile the program via "sbt compile", but as soon as I run "sbt run" on the program, I get the following issues. I suspect the foundational cause of the error is the following line:
`[error] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @754a850b'`
But I have no clue how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Here is all the printouts after running "sbt run":

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.9.8 (Oracle Corporation Java 17.0.10)
[info] loading settings for project leaptest-gui-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from C:\Users\ander\Documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\project
[info] loading settings for project leaptest-gui from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to leaptest-gui (in build file:/C:/Users/ander/Documents/GitHub/leaptest-gui/)
[info] running (fork) se.nullable.leaptest.MainAppLauncher
[error] Jan 31, 2024 11:39:52 AM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
[error] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @754a850b'
[error] Exception in Application start method
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[error]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
[error]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'LeapC':
[error] Det g´┐¢r inte att hitta den angivna modulen.
[error] Det g´┐¢r inte att hitta den angivna modulen.
[error] Det g´┐¢r inte att hitta den angivna modulen.
[error] Native library (win32-x86-64/LeapC.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\job-1\target\ab2feebf\374616d6\leaptest-gui_2.13-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\08cd5fbe\ffe73536\scala-library-2.13.12.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c2771f72\0a5dac89\jssc-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1db66ac1\21b6ddac\guice-6.0.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c802d291\a944a20d\javafx-controls-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\dfd377ee\d75b4952\javafx-graphics-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1490c8a6\05d8a190\javafx-fxml-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\7102852d\167b1684\jna-5.14.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\05068654\72c6282d\grizzled-scala_2.13-4.10.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\4c28a92c\6db1042c\upickle_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\948c91cc\308b305c\play-json_2.13-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\8640a521\fc2d3da6\monocle-core_2.13-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\ef225db6\9da8a373\monocle-macro_2.13-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\36abfe4d\ed29cbc9\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c2d81012\649a970f\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\b2371cb1\849273b3\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1492a67c\97d191dc\guava-31.0.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\a77712cf\1d7f9296\javafx-controls-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\545fde45\1d8d3465\javafx-graphics-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\9a145369\4fc329a4\javafx-base-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c28d32e6\2b0e4a50\javafx-fxml-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\95b2d459\bb4a0f87\scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\05fac3b2\67a17ff0\ujson_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\5726b533\e4aabe23\upack_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\4e572808\b0060b19\upickle-implicits_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1c805d21\e69778d3\play-functional_2.13-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\946352d0\8898ac8b\scala-reflect-2.13.12.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\2d89a07a\48cb4425\jackson-core-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\d09d8fd7\a5f4aeeb\jackson-annotations-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\38d92eb3\6755fb45\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\bcde750b\dfe9e616\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\4b1f3e61\61cbdf05\jackson-databind-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\a00b6c63\4ed08f61\cats-core_2.13-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\81b97ddf\2effeba7\cats-free_2.13-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\d02c4415\ec70de85\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\6349d92b\7525adc2\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\2335d250\1dddabdd\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\0d5d12e8\c48839d2\checker-qual-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\a28d2eb7\0ce067e7\error_prone_annotations-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\d2052ed0\24a9baaf\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\3e776bff\18867740\javafx-base-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\970275fc\323257f4\upickle-core_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\327bbcb5\cbaf8162\cats-kernel_2.13-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\9d8052c2\01ac730b\geny_2.13-1.0.0.jar)
[error]         at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:325)
[error]         at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:481)
[error]         at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:197)
[error]         at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:618)
[error]         at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:592)
[error]         at se.nullable.leaptest.leapc.LeapCLibrary$.<clinit>(LeapCLibrary.scala:27)
[error]         at se.nullable.leaptest.leapc.LeapController.connect(LeapController.scala:12)
[error]         at se.nullable.leaptest.MainApp.start(MainApp.scala:20)
[error]         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
[error]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
[error]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
[error]         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
[error]         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[error]         at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
[error]         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
[error]         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
[error]         ... 1 more
[error]         Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Det g´┐¢r inte att hitta den angivna modulen.
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:213)
[error]                 ... 16 more
[error]         Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Det g´┐¢r inte att hitta den angivna modulen.
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:226)
[error]                 ... 16 more
[error]         Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Det g´┐¢r inte att hitta den angivna modulen.
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:286)
[error]                 ... 16 more
[error]         Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (win32-x86-64/LeapC.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\job-1\target\ab2feebf\374616d6\leaptest-gui_2.13-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\08cd5fbe\ffe73536\scala-library-2.13.12.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c2771f72\0a5dac89\jssc-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1db66ac1\21b6ddac\guice-6.0.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c802d291\a944a20d\javafx-controls-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\dfd377ee\d75b4952\javafx-graphics-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1490c8a6\05d8a190\javafx-fxml-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\7102852d\167b1684\jna-5.14.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\05068654\72c6282d\grizzled-scala_2.13-4.10.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\4c28a92c\6db1042c\upickle_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\948c91cc\308b305c\play-json_2.13-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\8640a521\fc2d3da6\monocle-core_2.13-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\ef225db6\9da8a373\monocle-macro_2.13-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\36abfe4d\ed29cbc9\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c2d81012\649a970f\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\b2371cb1\849273b3\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1492a67c\97d191dc\guava-31.0.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\a77712cf\1d7f9296\javafx-controls-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\545fde45\1d8d3465\javafx-graphics-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\9a145369\4fc329a4\javafx-base-21.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\c28d32e6\2b0e4a50\javafx-fxml-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\95b2d459\bb4a0f87\scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\05fac3b2\67a17ff0\ujson_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\5726b533\e4aabe23\upack_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\4e572808\b0060b19\upickle-implicits_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\1c805d21\e69778d3\play-functional_2.13-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\946352d0\8898ac8b\scala-reflect-2.13.12.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\2d89a07a\48cb4425\jackson-core-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\d09d8fd7\a5f4aeeb\jackson-annotations-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\38d92eb3\6755fb45\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\bcde750b\dfe9e616\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\4b1f3e61\61cbdf05\jackson-databind-2.14.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\a00b6c63\4ed08f61\cats-core_2.13-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\81b97ddf\2effeba7\cats-free_2.13-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\d02c4415\ec70de85\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\6349d92b\7525adc2\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\2335d250\1dddabdd\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\0d5d12e8\c48839d2\checker-qual-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\a28d2eb7\0ce067e7\error_prone_annotations-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\d2052ed0\24a9baaf\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\3e776bff\18867740\javafx-base-21.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\970275fc\323257f4\upickle-core_2.13-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\327bbcb5\cbaf8162\cats-kernel_2.13-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ander\documents\GitHub\leaptest-gui\target\bg-jobs\sbt_12672224\target\9d8052c2\01ac730b\geny_2.13-1.0.0.jar)
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1141)
[error]                 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:297)
[error]                 ... 16 more
[error] Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 31 Jan 2024, 11:39:54
```

I was expecting the program to run, but I kept getting error messages. I have tried Googling the issue but couldn't conclude anything yet.

Comment: I think the problem is `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'LeapC'`, not the warning. According to this post you can just ignore the warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67854230/9973516

Comment: You have a good point! I will try that after lunch. Thank you!

Comment: It may be you are using the wrong **JDK**, usually the **JDK** is retro compatible and you can use the newest one to run old software. But, that stops to be the case when you add GUI libraries like **JavaFX**. You probably need to use a very specific one.

Comment: In terms of Luis's point about JDK versions, I think JavaFX 8 only works with JDK 8, JavaFX 11 -> 20 works with JDK 11 or higher, and JavaFX 21+ -> works with JDK 17 or higher (I could be wrong, but I think those are roughly the mappings).  As your logs indicate you are using JavaFX 21, it should work with any JDK 17+.

Comment: A search for LeapC returns: [LeapC is a C-style API for accessing tracking data from the Leap Motion service](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/v4/index.html).  I don't think that is related to JavaFX (nor Scala).  It appears that the DLL is being accessed via [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) and the required DLL is not present in the [load library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783632/how-do-i-load-and-use-native-library-in-java).