# c++ Javafx Application create exe via JVM.dll. it gives Error

Tags: java, c++, javafx

I can achieve creating exe file for normal java application. But i can not achieve exe file my javafx application.

I try change VM option.

My code summary.

```
#include <jni.h>

int main() {
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
    JavaVMOption* vmOption = new JavaVMOption[3];
    vmOption[0].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=..\\ayrtm.jar";
    vmOption[1].optionString = (char *)"--module-path ..\\jfx\\lib";
    vmOption[2].optionString = (char *)"--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.web";

    JavaVMInitArgs vmInitArgs;
    vmInitArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
    vmInitArgs.options = vmOption;
    vmInitArgs.nOptions = 3;
    vmInitArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVM* jvm;
    jint jvmProc = (createJavaVm)(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vmInitArgs);
    if (jvmProc < 0 || jvm == NULL || env == NULL) {
        FreeLibrary(jvmDLL);
        cout << "create jvm error" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

It gives ERROR

```
 \[info\] Registering natives for Native class
\[warn\] Could not find Native class Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280) at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244) at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:261) at com.sun.javafx.perf.PerformanceTracker.logEvent(PerformanceTracker.java:100) at javafx.scene.Node.\<clinit\>(Node.java:417) at ahmi.AHMI.\<clinit\>(AHMI.java:51) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94) at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) \[err\] Could not find or initialize main class java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at ahmi.AHMI.\<clinit\>(AHMI.java:51) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:273) at com.sun.javafx.perf.PerformanceTracker.logEvent(PerformanceTracker.java:100) at javafx.scene.Node.\<clinit\>(Node.java:417) ... 1 more
```

Comment: Please post the error as a code. Don't post it as a plain text and don't try to escape chars with using \: select the text of the pasted error and press the button { }.

Comment: I'm guessing but it sounds like your application is failing to find Microsoft's Direct 3D DLLs. If so then it should just be a matter of including their location on your PATH.

Comment: The native libraries required by JavaFX could not be loaded.  Those native libraries are the DLLs from the [JavaFX SDK download](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).  Normally they end up on the [java load library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783632/how-do-i-load-and-use-native-library-in-java) automatically for properly packaged and executed JavaFX applications.  I have no idea how to make that happen with your current approach.

Comment: You can use [warp packer to a create an exe out of a JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811401/how-to-create-a-standalone-exe-in-java-that-runs-without-an-installer-and-a-jr) if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your all reply.  I paste all Javafx dll's the path, it is running.

Comment: I upvoted your question, with enough reputation, [you will be able to answer it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).