# Using JInput in Intellij Idea project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jinput

I'm developing a game in Java (8) using Intellij Idea. Since I need controller support (XBox Controllers and the like), I seems the JInput library would help me support that.

I added the `net.java.jinput:jinput:2.0.6` library via maven (project structure > libraries), but when I run it, I get the following:

```
WARNING: Attempting to use default windows plug-in.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jinput-dx8 in java.library.path
```

I did some googling and fiddled around with it but I'm not able to get this working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java error - cannot find library in java.library.path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195778/java-error-cannot-find-library-in-java-library-path)

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here: http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_IntelliJ_IDEA

Basically, you create a folder called 'lib' in the project root, then put all the native DLL's there.
Finally, you add `-Djava.library.path=lib/` to the VM options in the run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still confused, here is another description of the method to download and [link DLLs for JInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783053/how-can-i-build-and-run-my-gradle-project-when-it-needs-binary-library-files-j/50612473#50612473)