# Java with JACOB - How to properly set Java Library Path

Tags: java, jacob

I'm challenging with a problem with library path and jacob. Ok, so let's go to the beginning.

I'm writting an application which needs to use jacob library etc - this applications has to be run as JAR file and here is the whole goal. I'm loading the library using System.load() method - works fine. Inside the code I have declared a method which extracts the jacob.dll file to the external folder, afterwards this path needs to me add to the java library path, what is done by:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);
```

But when I run my JAR I'm getting an unsatisfied link error. So my question is, how to add the path where the dll file is extracted?

P.S.
When I add the path in project properties - Native library everything works fine but the problem is that it's impossible to set java temp in native library.

Do anyone have idea what can I do with this sort of problem?

Answer (score 0):

See this:

- [Is -Djava.library.path=... equivalent to System.setProperty("java.library.path", ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419039/is-djava-library-path-equivalent-to-system-setpropertyjava-library-path)

You can try:

- http://fahdshariff.blogspot.fr/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html?m=1

Or:

- http://nicklothian.com/blog/2008/11/19/modify-javalibrarypath-at-runtime/

Regards