# IntelliJ Idea and JNI: Making Sure DLL's Are Where They Need to be for Execution

Tags: java, dll, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

I am working with a third party library in a project, and it includes two .dll files and a .jar fie to provide a JNI Wrapper. The test project that the third party vendor included in the .jar file can be called using the following command:

```
java -cp product.jar com.company.samples.product.Test
```

This works just fine, as long as the .jar and both of the dll's are in the same directory.

In my project I have placed the jar file and the dll's in the same directory, and then referenced the jar file as a library in IntelliJ Idea, but this causes the library to be unable to find the dll's. Is there a way that I can tell Idea where the dll's are so it can output them in the same directory as the jar file during execution?

Answer (score 9):

In IntelliJ when you would like to add a directory where **.dll** is found do:

1) Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. **Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S**).

2) In the left-hand pane of the dialog, select Modules.

3) In the pane to the right, select the module of interest.

4) In the right-hand part of the dialog, on the Module page, select the Dependencies tab.

5) On the Dependencies tab, click "+" and select Jars or directories.

6) In the dialog that opens, **select the necessary** files and **folders**. **These may be** individual .class and .java files, directories and archives (.jar and .zip) containing such files as well as **directories with Java native libraries** (**.dll**, .so or .jnilib). **Click OK.**

See for original explanation on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#d1860048e28 .

This is how I add **.dll** (**sql_auth.dll**) for JDBC driver to use integrated security of MS SQL.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `java.library.path` system property to point out to Java where to look for native libraries.

```
-Djava.library.path=path/to/dll
```

Note, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408467/706724), it is a read-only field that is checked before you have the opportunity to change it in code, but they provide a work-around.  In general, I have never needed to set the value at runtime compared to at launch.

Answer (score 2):

The DLL are loaded from [path variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). You could change the value when launching the application.

Alternatively, you can  construct the path to dll (again by using environment variable /system variable) and load it via [System.load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29)