# How do I add sqljdbc_auth.dll to my project build path?

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, dll, sqljdbc

I have a project that connects to msSQL Server, the project is exported as a war file then run in Apache, but when I try to connect to the SQL Server it gives me this error. 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI 
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path. - See screenprint below

I've added the dll to the jre native library in eclipse, I've added it to the bin and lib folders of the jre folder in program files, I've added it to the eclipse.ini file with java -Djava.library.path= and I've also tried the -djava line in cmd prompt. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: did you try the following:  String path = " path of the file sqljdbc_auth.dll";
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);

Comment: Thanks Win, I got it working by adding the sqljdbc_auth.dll to the Java/JDK/bin

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42572544/1737819