# no lwjgl in java.library.path

Tags: eclipse, lwjgl

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
```

How to fix this error ?

My VM arguments is:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Benas\workspace\Libss\lwjgl\native\windows\
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LWJGL 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError': no lwjgl in java.library.path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592513/lwjgl-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of LWJGL are you using? As of LWJGL3, you have to select C:\Users\Benas\workspace\Libss\lwjgl\native\windows\x64\ . You should also check whether the folder actually exists and contains lwjgl.dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse, you can set the native-libary path.
Right-click on your project and then click 'Properties'.
Go to 'Java build path' and expand JRE System Libary.
You will see 'Native libary location', select that en click edit.
Then click 'External folder', en select your \lwjgl\native\windows\ folder.

Hope it helped :)