# How can i use the lwjgl in bluej?

Tags: java, lwjgl, bluej

The lwjgl consists of two parts.
I set up the java part by copying the `"lwjgl.jar"` into the `"...\BlueJ\lib\userlib"` folder and that worked.
For the native part I have to point the java.library.path at the two DLLs `"lwjgl.dll"` and `"OpenAL32.dll"`. How do I do that?

Comment: Not even sure it can be done with blueJ. Should consider using eclipse (unless you're using the BlueJ Java textbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWJGL looks in a special variable to find its native libs. I don't know how blueJ works but you should do something like:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("pathToNatives").getAbsolutePath());
```

More info and another way to set this up is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592513/lwjgl-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path/24604712#24604712)