# How can i use lwjgl in BlueJ

Tags: java, lwjgl, bluej

So it is easy to get the .jar part tunning but i dont know what to do with the natives things. Where do i have to put them? Because now when i run my program it always says: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path (in java.lang.ClassLoader)". I mean i get the problem but how do i solve it? Is there any tutorial on how to get lwjgl running in BlueJ? I need it for a school project and we musn`t use eclipse.
I also already saw this post ([How can i use the lwjgl in bluej?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319154/how-can-i-use-the-lwjgl-in-bluej)) but i dont get what to do.

Comment: Did you read the linked post? Replace "pathToNatives" with the path on your hard drive... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592513/lwjgl-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path/24604712#24604712

Comment: Sorry but i dont know much about programming, pretty new to it. Where would I have to put the line " System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("pathToNatives").getAbsolutePath());" then?

Comment: Preferably in a section of code that is executed. Like the main method

Comment: Now it says it cant find class File, what do i have to do? I guess i need to import something but what? (Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/23631ed7328918b696d023d17b295a4e)

Answer (score 0):

`.jar`s go in `/usr/share/bluej/userlib`, and, as [@OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) said, put in you main method

```java
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("/usr/share/bluej/userlib/lwjglnatives").getAbsolutePath());
```