# java.lang.reflect.inaccessibleobjectexception unable to make jdk.internal.loader.classloaders

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, classloader, java-9

i have a exceptionlike **java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader(jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader,jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath) accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @45f08579** 
after i use a library **compile group: 'com.github.snowindy', name:'scriptlet4docx', version: '0.8.6'**

i found some solution like 
1. java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED  from here [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m/41265267) 
2. java --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs=ALL-UNNAMED -jar scriptlet4docx-0.8.6.jar

so i tried to run this commande in my terminal, but it doesn't work. and also i tried add vm option like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5IM.png)

or here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4cYr.png)
but both of them don't work...

I used the default version of jdk in intellij jdk11.

Comment: In your case the library is named : ```If the reflecting code is in a named module, ALL-UNNAMED can be replaced by its name.```

Answer (score 8):

In fact the post solution says that you have to make a mirror with the jvm of the blow the option of jvm is not in intellij but in gradle.

so i add this code in build.gradle and then it works

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += ['--add-opens', 'java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED']
}
```